# expression to change the fill colour of textbox if the date is greater or equal to 7 days before the expected end date column

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

i have a report that shows a tenancies expected end date in the last column and a textbox in the column to the left that uses the expression =DateAdd("d", -7, Fields!exp_tncy_end.value) to show the date 7 days before the expected end date so if the expected end date was 13/09/20 then textbox21 would display 6/9/20

many of these expected end dates are way in the future

what i would like to happen is that as we approach the week that the exp_tncy_end date is due i would like the date in textbox21 to change to red, see circled example below

[example of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjnpd.png)

can anyone help with an expression that would achieve this?

regards

Kieran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the color property in the textbox you want to change to this...

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Today(),  Fields!exp_tncy_end.Value) <=7, "Red", "Black")
```

Note that this will calculate the based on the day number, not a 24 hour period so you might want to adjust the number of days you check for to suit your specific needs.